# fluidpages / flux inheritance performance

Tags: inheritance, fluid, flux, typo3-6.2.x, fedext

When using fluidpages, fluidcontent and flux in TYPO3 6.2 the time to load a page in *list mode* takes more than a minute in our environment, which was not the case with TYPO3 4.7.

After looking into the code I have the feeling that it is connected to the *field or attribute inheritance* of the flexform configuration inside the templates.

Attached is a [profiling result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRLSy.png). 
76000 calls for PageProvider->getForm() is a lot.

According to the [docs](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/using-templates/template-inheritance.html) there is a way to disable inheritance for single fields by *stopInheritance="TRUE"*.

But is there also a way to disable it in general, so that I don't have to add it to every field manually?

Comment: Are you using a templating library? If so, you could loop through the fields and insert the `stopInheritance="TRUE"` for each one.

Answer (score 0):

When you comment these hooks everything works smoothly:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['GLOBAL']['recStatInfoHooks']['flux'] = 'FluidTYPO3\\Flux\\Hooks\\ContentIconHookSubscriber->addSubIcon';
if (TRUE === version_compare(TYPO3_version, '7.1', '<')) {
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['GLOBAL']['recStatInfoHooks']['flux'] = 'FluidTYPO3\\Flux\\Hooks\\LegacyContentIconHookSubscriber->addSubIcon';
}
```

I have the feeling that the icon detection is not made for huge record lists. We use fluidpages for rendering and FLUX is necessary for this. So there is no need for 'addSubIcon' calls which end up in timeouts cause on inherited flexform checkups for each record and its relations.